# moving files from a batch job to blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

I am executing an azure-batch job, which creates a zip file as its output.  The batch is being executed by an orchestrator with the responsibility of moving the output files to blob.  I have this working, but it feels clunky - i.e. I download the file locally to the orchestrator then upload to blob:

```
CloudTask task; // executed task...
var node = task.GetNodeFile(fileName);
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(localFile))
{
  node.CopyToStream(stream);
}

var blobRef = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFileName);
blobRef.UploadFromFile(localFile, FileMode.Open);
```

I tried passing the blob stream to the CopyToStream method directly, but nothing was moved to the blob:

```
node.CopyToStream(blobRef.OpenWrite());
```

Is it possible to copy the output file from a batch vm to blob without this extra hop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a memory stream:

```
CloudTask task; // executed task...
var node = task.GetNodeFile(fileName);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    node.CopyToStream(ms);

    var blobRef = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFileName);
    blobRef.UploadFromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It did occur to me, the only issue being some of the zip files will we well over 1gb, maybe even 3 or 4.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it is a working solution and I didn't mention the file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was actually quite simple - disposing the cloud ref stream seems to force a flush - i.e.:

```
CloudTask task; // executed task...
var node = task.GetNodeFile(fileName);

using(var stream = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFileName))
{
  node.CopyToStream(stream);
}
```